# Expand/Collapse all expanders

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a list of expanders which I want to control its expanded state(IsExpanded) with global toggle button which should toggle between expanded/collapsed state.

The solution which I have got so far does that by binding the expander's IsExpanded state to the togglebutton's IsChecked state. This works as long as I dont manually dont toggle the expanders. Once I do that those particular expanders dont respect the binding (toggle button's IsChecked state).

Any idea why? and is there a clean solution in XAML for this?

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>  
  <StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton Name="ExpandAll">Toggle</ToggleButton>  
    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding ElementName=ExpandAll,Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}">
      Hai
    </Expander>
    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding ElementName=ExpandAll,Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}">
      Hello
    </Expander>
    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding ElementName=ExpandAll,Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}">
      Weird
    </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this *entirely* in XAML, but the following allows you to do it with an `IValueConverter`:

```
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:Converter x:Key="Converter" />
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <ToggleButton Name="ExpandAll">
            <ToggleButton.IsChecked>
                <MultiBinding Mode="OneWayToSource" Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="Expander1" Path="IsExpanded" />
                    <Binding ElementName="Expander2" Path="IsExpanded" />
                    <Binding ElementName="Expander3" Path="IsExpanded" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </ToggleButton.IsChecked>
            Toggle</ToggleButton>
        <Expander Name="Expander1">
            Hai
        </Expander>
        <Expander Name="Expander2">
            Hello
        </Expander>
        <Expander Name="Expander3">
            Weird
        </Expander>
    </StackPanel>
```

And your `Converter` is as below:

```
public class Converter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //we're using OneWayToSource, so this will never be used.
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // we want to convert the single 'IsChecked' value from the ToggleButton into 
        // 3 'IsExpanded' values
        var allValues = new object[targetTypes.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < allValues.Length; i++)
        {
            allValues[i] = value;
        }

        return allValues;
    }
}
```

This works by setting up a `OneWayToSource` binding between the `IsChecked` property of the `ToggleButton` (i.e. the binding will be *set* against the source when the target value changes), and uses an `IMultiValueConverter` to translate the single value into one for each of the `Expander`s.

Comment: Hi Steve, That works. Do you know how this solution could be modified if the expanders werent fixed and were generated by a ItemsControl?

Comment: @Pradeep - no, I don't think that will be possible using this method as the `MultiBinding` needs a concrete list of `Binding`s.  If that is required then you may need to look at implementing a view model or (god forbid) some code behind

Comment: @Steve Greatrex: What does the binding in the OP question breaks after we manually expand/collapse? Is there a better approach in the WPF4 than what you have here? Any comments?

Comment: Also, `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` and `Mode=TwoWay` does the trick for me.

Answer (score 7):

I know that this post is very old. Just posting this for anyone else who comes across. The below code worked for me.

```
<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding ElementName=ExpandAll, Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
</Expander>
```

This works when the expanders are generated dynamically, for example inside a `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate`.